# How to get FlatList items loading from AsyncStorage saved json?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make a FlatList that gets its data from AsyncStorage. The problem is Im not able to get this to work, the timing seems messed up and the array passed to the FlatList is always blank.

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);
var searchHistory = [];

const _retrieveData = async () => {
    try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('searchHistory');
        if (value !== null) {
          searchHistory = JSON.parse(value);
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log("_retrieveData failed!! " + error);
    }
  }
  _retrieveData();

const expandedSearch = () => {
    if(expanded) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <FlatList 
            data={searchHistory}
            renderItem={renderHistoryItem}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  }
...
{expandedSearch()}
```

I have a toggled View (expandedSearch) that displays a FlatList of search history items. For some reason the searchHistory array is blank when the FlatList gets rendered, even when the expandedSearch view is toggled...which should re-render the Flatlist?

Answer (score 0):

**For some reason the searchHistory array is blank when the FlatList gets rendered**

=> because of your definition of `var searchHistory = [];`

`AsyncStorage.getItem('searchHistory');` is an await function, so it takes time to get the response.

Your component will render like that:

Init `searchHistory` with empty array, then render `FlatList`, then fill `searchHistory` with response from `AsyncStorage`. Because `searchHistory` is a variable, not a state, so that when its value changes, component will not rerender.

=> Solution:

Change `var searchHistory = [];` => `const [searchHistory,setSearchHistory] = useState([])`
and change `searchHistory = JSON.parse(value);` => `setSearchHistory(JSON.parse(value))`

Answer (score 0):

**you need to do this changes**

replace `var searchHistory = [];` with `[searchHistory, setSearchHistory] = React.useState([]);`

replace `searchHistory = JSON.parse(value);` with `setSearchHistory(JSON.parse(value))`;

**and this the Explanition**

you use `promise async/await` to get data

so you need to rerender component after data is ready to notifiy flatlist with data,
you can do this by call `setSearchHistory` and this will rerender your component